# How to mock different responses from constructor with PowerMock

Tags: java, powermock

I'm getting an error from PowerMock when running the following:

```
whenNew(Socket.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(server).thenCallRealMethod();
```

The error is:

> You probably stored a reference to OngoingStubbing returned by when() and 
>   called stubbing methods like thenReturn() on this reference more than once.
>
> Examples of correct usage:
>      when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false).thenThrow(exception);
>      when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true, false).thenThrow(exception);

Any idea how I can return my mock object on the first `new` and afterwards call the default constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any built-in solution, but try this one, it's supposed to work:

```
whenNew(Socket.class).withAnyArguments().thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    boolean firstCall;

    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {             
        if (firstCall) {
            firstCall = false;
            return server;
        }
        return invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();
    }
});
```

With `thenAnswer` you can implement any logic for mocking a method inside an `Answer`.

So, if you need such a behavior often, I would suggest you encapsulating it into a class like this:

```
class MockOnlyFirstCall<T> implements Answer<T> {
    private final T firstCallResult;
    private boolean firstCall = true;

    public MockOnlyFirstCall(T firstCallResult) {
        this.firstCallResult = firstCallResult;
    }

    @Override
    public T answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {             
        if (firstCall) {
            firstCall = false;
            return firstCallResult;
        }
        return invocationOnMock.callRealMethod();
    }
}
```

Then you could just do

```
whenNew(Socket.class)
    .withAnyArguments()
    .thenAnswer(new MockOnlyFirstCall<>(server));
```